# Terrafom referencing map output in module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform module as follows

```
module "vpc" {
  source                      = "./modules"
  my_aws_account_id           = "<aws_account_id>"
  my_aws_vpc_id               = "<aws_vpc_id>"
  my_vpc_peering_connections  = {
    stage    = "<aws_stage_vpc_id>"
    preprod  = "<aws_preprod_vpc_id>"
  }
  my_vpc_route_table          = {
    default   = {
      name    = "test-default"
      routes  = [{
        cidr_block                  = "10.10.16.0/20"
        vpc_peering_connection_id   = module.vpc.op_vpc_peering_connections["stage"]
      }, {
        cidr_block                  = "10.10.32.0/20"
        vpc_peering_connection_id   = module.vpc.op_vpc_peering_connections["preprod"]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

variable

```
variable "my_aws_account_id" {
  type  = string
}

variable "my_aws_vpc_id" {
  type  = string
}

variable "my_vpc_peering_connections" {
  type  = map(string)
}

variable "my_vpc_route_table" {
  type  = object({
    default = object({
      name    = string
      routes  = list(object({
        cidr_block                  = string
        vpc_peering_connection_id   = string
      }))
    })
  })
}
```

resource

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "peering_connections" {
  for_each      = var.my_vpc_peering_connections

  peer_owner_id = var.my_aws_account_id
  peer_vpc_id   = each.value
  vpc_id        = var.my_aws_vpc_id
  tags          = {
    Name = each.key
  }

  timeouts {}
}

resource "aws_route_table" "default_route_table" {
  vpc_id    = var.my_aws_vpc_id
  tags      = {
    Name = var.my_vpc_route_table.default.name
  }

  dynamic "route" {
    for_each = var.my_vpc_route_table.default.routes
    content {
      cidr_block                  = lookup(route.value, "cidr_block")
      vpc_peering_connection_id   = lookup(route.value, "vpc_peering_connection_id")

      instance_id                 = ""
      gateway_id                  = ""
      carrier_gateway_id          = ""
      destination_prefix_list_id  = ""
      egress_only_gateway_id      = ""
      ipv6_cidr_block             = ""
      local_gateway_id            = ""
      nat_gateway_id              = ""
      network_interface_id        = ""
      transit_gateway_id          = ""
      vpc_endpoint_id             = ""
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc_peering_connection.peering_connections
  ]
}
```

output

```
output op_vpc_peering_connections {
  value = tomap({
    for name, details in aws_vpc_peering_connection.peering_connections : name => details.id
  })
}
```

but when I run the following commands the first one success and the second one fails with an error

```
> terraform import module.vpc.aws_vpc_peering_connection.peering_connections["stage"] <peering_connection_id>
> terraform import module.vpc.aws_vpc_peering_connection.peering_connections["preprod"] <peering_connection_id>
```

error

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on /Users/sarad/workspace/personal/terraform-for-each/main.tf line 33, in module "vpc":
│   33:         vpc_peering_connection_id   = module.vpc.op_vpc_peering_connections["preprod"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc.op_vpc_peering_connections is map of string with 1 element
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
```

the error goes comes if I have more than 1 element in op_vpc_peering_connections and I am trying to reference them in module by name like `module.vpc.op_vpc_peering_connections["stage"]` or `module.vpc.op_vpc_peering_connections["preprod"]`

also, I am unable to debug the output with `terraform output` where I get the following warning

```
╷
│ Warning: No outputs found
│ 
│ The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs are empty. Please define an output in your configuration with the `output` keyword and run `terraform
│ refresh` for it to become available. If you are using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You can use the `terraform console` command to assist.
╵
```

Answer (score 0):

If you first run a `terraform plan` you will see the exact name of each resource. At which point all you have to do is copy/paste those names out of the `plan` output and into your `terraform import` command. This also allows you to validate each resource you think you have configured via `for_each`. That should be your first step to see why the `module.vpc.aws_vpc_peering_connection.peering_connections["preprod"]` doesn't exist like you expect it to.

> also, I am unable to debug the output with terraform output where I get the following warning

That's because the output only exists inside the module, and `terraform output` only gives you the top-level outputs. Somewhere at the top-level of your Terraform code, like inside the file with the `module "vpc" { ... }` declaration, you need to add a top-level output:

```
output op_vpc_peering_connections {
  value = module.vpc.op_vpc_peering_connections
}
```